# Echo String from TXT in PHP

Tags: php, file

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <?php 
    $file = file_get_contents('data/data.txt');
    echo $file;
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And want to display the line in data.txt.
Which looks like this:

```
08/08/19-13:40:01;22.875;
```

I searched Google for this topic but all the answers seems not to work for me.

Comment: Does the file get read successfully?

Try the following to look what is inside the $file variable:
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($file);
echo "</pre>";

Comment: var_dump() it. Did the file load? If not check the path is OK

Comment: try attaching the .txt file to your question

Comment: @lucamuh you are right it does not get read right if i open data/data.txt but IT works with data.txt

Answer (score 0):

read the text per line ?....

```
$data = file_get_contents("input.txt"); //read the file
$convert = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line

for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++)  
{
    echo $convert[$i].';'; //write value by index
}
?>

++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Output :
one;two;three;four;five;
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#102319

Comment: By running your Code i get only an Output Like ";"

Comment: But if i Put the File in the root folder and Open it like "Data.txt" it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just search for the string: https://3v4l.org/Pc7GR

```
<?php

// $simpulated = file_get_contents("data/data.txt");

$simulated = '
gjhgfgshaffhdfhsds
gsdfdgfebrewujbflken
fkdnwjefwibiuwbfbef
000:000:000:000;

06/06/19-11:11:11;11.111;
08/08/19-13:40:01;22.875;
10/11/19-10:00:00;20.000;
';

preg_match_all("/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};\d{2}\.\d{3};/", $simulated, $matches);

if(count($matches["0"]) > 0) {
    array_map(function($match) { echo $match . "\n"; }, $matches["0"]);
}
```

`preg_match_all("/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};\d{2}\.\d{3};/", $simulated, $matches);`
Is a regex command that matches `\d` (number(s)), `{2}` two of something (numbers in this case), `\.` matches a dot (.)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Could you comment me the following Line i do Not get it right:

Comment: preg_match_all("/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2};\d{2}\.\d{3};/", $simulated, $matches;

Comment: your missing the end parenthesis `..., $simulated, $matches);`

Comment: searches for the given regex expression, if it finds a match, stores it in a variable and makes it available for use.